# If data changes, how to show only new changes?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

​Hello!

With the help of the function, data is loaded that is constantly (every minute) automatically changed in the "dynamic data" column. This data is updated in all rows at once.

**​​My task:
If the value of B7 has changed since the last change, then we display the "name: Delta" in cell C7. If not, leave the cell C7 empty. The file have little example.**
[link to excel file in googlesheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ko34Yekb3PhIYS7JvRWQey5z9gl_ghnK/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105287646588317361913&rtpof=true&sd=true)

I use excel addition "[excelpricefeed](https://www.excelpricefeed.com/)" for dynamical data
​

​This VBA will be work for the rest of the rows below.

There are many such lines (more than 600)"
​
*​​Unfortunately, I have a code that only works for one row and it does not accept changes via a function (because the data is passed from a third-party application via a function)​*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A6")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("A6").Value = Dynamic_data Then
        Range("B6").Value = ""
    Else
        Dynamic_data = Range("A6").Value
        Range("B6").Value = "Delta"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Worksheet_Change` is fine but it might fire even 600 times during an update. Another difficulty is that you can not know the previous values after a worksheet change so you need to store the values somewhere else. It can be a hidden sheet or an invisible column on the actual sheet (either hidden or somewhere far on the right). Another difficulty can be that there may be a time gap between first and last update so if you need the Delta be displayed until the next update you'd need to bother with the time stamps that would make the processing even more complex. So I'd suggest a different concept: Use `Worksheet_Change` just to set flag to indicate that something happened in the data column (the flag can be set 600 times, that's no problem). The run an update process regulary and do the necessary updates when the flag is set. The timing of the update process will introduce some delay in updating display, but you can adjust it depending according to the behaviour of the external data update.

Suppose you have data in column A, "Delta" is displayed in column B, the previous values are in column BB:

Put this code in Sheet1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not UpdateStarted Then
        UpdateRequired = True
        UpdateProc ' launch update sub
    End If
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub   ' changes in column A are processed only
    UpdateRequired = True
End Sub
```

And this code to a code modul (e.g. Modul1):

```
Option Explicit

Public UpdateRequired As Boolean
Public UpdateStarted As Boolean

Public Sub UpdateProc()

    Dim rData As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim t10sec As Double
    t10sec = TimeValue("0:0:10")

    Application.OnTime Now + t10sec, "UpdateProc"    ' restart
    UpdateStarted = True
    
    If Not UpdateRequired Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set rData = Range("A6:A700")
    For Each v In rData
        If v.Value = Cells(v.Row, "BB") Then   ' compare to saved value
            Cells(v.Row, 2).Value = vbNullString    ' clear Delta for unchanged values
        Else
            Cells(v.Row, "BB") = v.Value  ' save changed value
            Cells(v.Row, "B") = "Delta"
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    UpdateRequired = False

End Sub
```

Notes:

You don't need to start UpdateProc. The `Worksheet_Change` will start it on the first change on sheet1.
UpdateProc will reschedule itself to run in every 10th seconds.