# How can I enter data quickly into cells using a scanner with automatically refreshing macro?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use a barcode scanner to enter information quickly. This information goes into  3 pivot tables and 3 pivot charts (Pivot tables are small with at most 24 lines and source data is around 5000 lines). The pivot charts and tables automatically refresh using the code below, but this slows down something so when I scan multiple items really quickly it does not record all of the data. It takes about 3 seconds for it to load and refresh the charts before I can enter new data into the next cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
 Dim pc As PivotCache
 
    'Refresh all pivot tables
    For Each pc In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
    pc.Refresh
    Next pc
End Sub
```

I have tried using this code in a module to help reduce some of the waiting, but I don't think it really makes a difference.

```
Sub SwitchOff(bSwitchOff As Boolean)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
    
  With Application
    If bSwitchOff Then

      ' OFF
      lCalcSave = .Calculation
        bScreenUpdate = .ScreenUpdating
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .EnableAnimations = False
      
      '
      ' switch off display pagebreaks for all worksheets
      '
      For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
      Next ws
    Else
 
      ' ON
      If .Calculation <> lCalcSave And lCalcSave <> 0 Then .Calculation = lCalcSave
      .ScreenUpdating = bScreenUpdate
      .EnableAnimations = True
      
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

I have also tried using other macros like the ones below to update the tables and charts but it does not work for some reason I am unsure of.

```
Sub RefreshPivotTableCache()
   Dim PivotCache As PivotCache
   For Each PivotCache In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
       PivotCache.RefreshAll
   Next PivotCache
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Worksheets("PivotTables").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
Worksheets("PivotTables").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: These symptoms indicates overload. Excel can not complete all operations to get ready for next scanner input. You may "slow down" Excel with a `DoEvents` after each new input to leave enough time for executing all commands. Another approach may be to update pivot tables asynchronouosly by running an updater process that refreshes the tables periodically. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207925/if-data-changes-how-to-show-only-new-changes/71223922#71223922

Comment: I'd also check whether the 1st `Worksheet_Change` recursively triggers itself by changing cell contents. You can prevent this with issuing the `Application.EnableEvents = False` before `.PivotCache.Refresh` and switch it on after.